# Fantasy romance movie with vampires and a black and red necklace

Tags: story-identification, movie, vampire

My sisters and I use to watch this supernatural romance movie, I don’t exactly remember all the details but I remember some. I know it was for sure supernatural, I think vampires maybe. It involved a necklace, maybe red or black. I believe it was about long lost lovers and I think they were buried together or something like that. I’m not sure if it’s a family movie or if it’s PG-13.

It’s at least from the 90s or 2000s could be late 80s as well.